# Updating the XML without deleting its contents

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I have developed lot of testcases, each testcase generates xml, output xml of one testcase become input xml for other testcase. I want all testcases should read data from a single xml file.There is a need to update the xml without deleting its current content or creating a new one....is it possible to do this??? Thanks in advance. Technology preferred is .net linq(my team forces to use this)

The testcases are unit test cases developed in c#

Comment: Your question is *really* unclear. Yes, you can certainly read an XML file, add elements to it, then write it out again. What problems have you run into when trying this? What update are you trying to make? Where does xslt (as tagged) come into this?

Comment: Just to put it in a simple word... i need to update an existing xml file(without deleting its content)... suppose i have 50 tags , i need to insert 51th tag without deleting 50 tags , is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Xml is basicly a flat text file (in some charset, ascii, utf8 .. etc..)

As any other text file, you can edit it by "in place character replacements", but you need to know the precise location of the characters you wan't to replace.

You could also append to a file without clearing it, by opening it in the correct mode.

However, it is extremely easier to parse it to DOM, close file, edit the DOM, and then rewrite the file. Even though that will delete the current content for a few moments.. depending on filesize, this will typically be milliseconds.

While you have opened the file for rewriting, the file would be locked by OS..